# multiple Jersey @Path s on single method

Tags: java, jersey

Using jersey - I know I can annotate a method with

```
@Path("/{a:path1|path2}")
```

but I was wandering if it was also possible to just use two annotations on a single method

```
@Path("path1")
@Path("path2")
```

To get almost the same effect (I know - this way I can not get a @PathParam ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only in Java 8 it is allowed to have more than one same annotation. And even more than that annotation should be marked specially (`@Repeatable`, see more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html)). Annotation `@Path` does not have such meta-annotation.

So, conclusion it is not possible.